# reinitialising an object not working

Tags: c#, .net

I am having some issues 'resetting' an object back to some default values.

So I have an object called point of type MPoint (my own class). If the point gets used more than a certain amount of times I wish to reset the point back to its default value. So I created a method called CheckPointExpired, shown below.

The issue is the method gets called and if the point property PointUsed is greater than MaxResuse it puts the point object to null and creates a new point. However when debugging my code back in the RunPoint method I can see the point object has not changed value. I do not understand why?

As I understand it when I pass the point object to the method CheckPointExpired it is being passed as a reference so surely any change to the object should be reflected back in the RunPoint method? Obviously I am not understanding something.

```
  public MPoint RunPoint(MPoint point)
  {
      // first check if point has expired
      CheckPointExpired(point)

      // rest of my code
  }

  void CheckPointExpired(MPoint point)
  {
     if (point.PointUsed >= point.MaxResuse)
     {
        int lvl = point.Level;
        int maxLB = point.MaxLookBack;
        int maxReuse = point.MaxResuse;
        int order = point.Order;            

        point = null;
        point = new MPoint(maxReuse, maxLB, lvl, order);
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass point as a reference using `ref` keyword:

```
void CheckPointExpired(ref MPoint point)
{
    if (point.PointUsed >= point.MaxResuse)
    {
       int lvl = point.Level;
       int maxLB = point.MaxLookBack;
       int maxReuse = point.MaxResuse;
       int order = point.Order;            

       point = null;
       point = new MPoint(maxReuse, maxLB, lvl, order);
   }
}

CheckPointExpired(ref point);
```

Otherwise you can only change the field or properties of point and they will be visible on the original object, but an assigment won't change the passed argument's reference.Even though classes are reference types,when you don't use `ref` the parameter actually a copy of the original reference.E.g:

```
string foo = "Foo";
string bar = foo;
```

Here the assignment `bar = foo` copies foo's reference to bar.So there are two distinct references that points the same location.Whenever you initialize bar with another value it just throws away the old reference and doesn't affect `foo`:

```
bar = "bar";
```

Comment: I see. I thought when you passed a object it was passed as a reference by default? So the object is actually being copied when I pass it?

Comment: @mHelpMe the object's reference is copied not the object itself.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to reference it on function in-order to change the value. You were passing it by value/read-only to function. `ref` Keyword is for reference, Means passing object by It's address, Which allows you to edit and or change the object Inside the function.

```
void CheckPointExpired(ref MPoint point)
  {
     if (point.PointUsed >= point.MaxResuse)
     {
        int lvl = point.Level;
        int maxLB = point.MaxLookBack;
        int maxReuse = point.MaxResuse;
        int order = point.Order;            

        point = null;
        point = new MPoint(maxReuse, maxLB, lvl, order);
     }
  }
```

You'll need to pass the address to function also, Otherwise the function won't be able to read address from your object.

```
public MPoint RunPoint(MPoint point)
  {
      // first check if point has expired
      CheckPointExpired(ref point)

      // rest of my code
  }
```